# Crear un menú con inicio a un lado y resto de secciones en el otro lado HTML CSS

Tags: html, css, css3

Básicamente estoy creando un menú y quiero que en la parte izquierda del menú aparezca HOME y en la parte derecha las secciones de la barra de navegación (Quiénes somos, Nuestros Servicios, Contacto). He conseguido hacerlo pero creo que el código es muy sucio, y me gustaría alguna forma de hacerlo de forma más limpia. Gracias.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Ejercicio de prueba menú</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@300;400;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <nav class="navbar">
        <a href="#" id="home">HOME</a>
        <a href="#" class="navlink" id="somos">Quiénes somos</a>
        <a href="#" class="navlink" id="servicios">Servicios</a>
        <a href="#" class="navlink" id="contacto">Contacto</a>
    </nav>
    
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
.navbar{
    display: flex;
    /* justify-content: space-around; */
   
}

#home{
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: none; 
    position: absolute;
    top: 15px;
    left: 100px;


}

.navlink{
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: none; 
   
}

#somos{
    position: absolute;
    top: 15px;
    right: 500px; 

}

#servicios{
    position: absolute;
    top: 15px;
    right: 300px; 

}

#contacto{
    position: absolute;
    top: 15px;
    right: 100px; 

}
```

Muchas gracias, saludos.

Comment: Para mi está limpio, esos menus por lo general se hacen con el combo `<ul>` y `<li>`. El hecho de hacerlo solo con un `<nav>` ya es muy sexy.

Answer (score 0):

Lo puedes conseguir de forma fácil con `flexbox`, para que esto funciones debes definir un `display:flex` para el padre, en este caso el `nav` y separar los hijos en dos para poder aplicar un `justify-content: space-between`.
Para separar los hijos en dos, agregaremos una nueva etiqueta para encapsular el resto de opciones del menú.

Te dejo un snippet a continuación

```css
nav{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.right-sections{
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Ejercicio de prueba menú</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@300;400;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <nav class="navbar">
        <a href="#" id="home">HOME</a>
        <div class="right-sections">
          <a href="#" class="navlink" id="somos">Quiénes somos</a>
          <a href="#" class="navlink" id="servicios">Servicios</a>
          <a href="#" class="navlink" id="contacto">Contacto</a>
        </div>
    </nav>
    
</body>
</html>
```